# Need to append html element as user keep clicking a button with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, append

I am trying to append a div multiple times when clicking a button, the problem is that is only appending once. I need to append same div as user keeps clicking.

- DIV I need to append multiple times is stored in a variable named `$htmlDivForm` in the jquery code.
- I'm using bootstrap.

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form id="formUser" action="index.html" method="post">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="moreFieldsBtn" class="btn" type="button" name="button">+</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            More Content...
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
var $moreFieldsBtn = $("#moreFieldsBtn");
var $formUser = $("#formUser");
var $htmlDivForm = $('<div class="form-group"><label class="labelName" for="inputText">Nombre</label><input class="form-control inputTextField" type="text" name="inputText" value=""></div>');


//Add input text field
$($moreFieldsBtn).click (function() {
    $($formUser).append($htmlDivForm);
});
```

Comment: just remove the $ symbol on this par of the variable $htmlDivForm  $('<div class="form-group"> @Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I had gone through your question.

I have Updated the example.

Removed the Object and just inserting plain HTML
```

```js
var $moreFieldsBtn = $("#moreFieldsBtn");
var $formUser = $("#formUser");
var $htmlDivForm = $('<div class="form-group"><label class="labelName" for="inputText">Nombre</label><input class="form-control inputTextField" type="text" name="inputText" value=""></div>');

var htmltext = '<div class="form-group"><label class="labelName" for="inputText">Nombre</label><input class="form-control inputTextField" type="text" name="inputText" value=""></div>'


//Add input text field
$($moreFieldsBtn).click (function() {
    $($formUser).append(htmltext);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">
            <form id="formUser" action="index.html" method="post">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button id="moreFieldsBtn" class="btn" type="button" name="button">+</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
            More Content...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
```

Comment: try above js fiddle

Comment: Please format your answer correctly, and include code in the answer itself.

Comment: I try your code on jsfiddle and it works! Unfortunately in my project still not working. Can you please take a look? https://github.com/danielbettech/Machotez Thanks!

Comment: Tell me the page name.So that i can look into it.

Comment: Its prueba1.html and app.js Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't append the same div multiple times, you need to instantiate new divs and attach those. You also don't need to re-wrap the jQuery objects to attach the handlers:

```
var $moreFieldsBtn = $("#moreFieldsBtn");
var $formUser = $("#formUser");

//Add input text field
$moreFieldsBtn.click(function() {
    var $htmlDivForm = $('<div class="form-group"><label class="labelName" for="inputText">Nombre</label><input class="form-control inputTextField" type="text" name="inputText" value=""></div>');
    $formUser.append($htmlDivForm);
});
```